# Find an equation of the parallel plane to the second plane

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let affine subspace of $\mathbb R^{3}$: 
> $H=af((1,1,0),(2,1,1),(1,2,0))$ and $L=(1,1,1)+span((-1,1,1))$.
> Find an equation of space $P$ which is parallel to $H$ and contains a point $(-1,2,-3)$.

I did this task but I have a lot of questions and I want to ask about it:
**(1)**  Is it true that when I have $H=af((1,1,0),(2,1,1),(1,2,0))$ then I can tell that $H: p(t,s)=(1,1,0)+(2,1,1)t+(1,2,0)s$? Can I always say that?
**(2)**  Assuming that the answer to (1) is affirmative, do you think that if $P||H$ then $P$ it is spread out by the same vectors as $H$ so parametric equation differs only point: $P: q(t,s)=(-1,2,-3)+(2,1,1)t+(1,2,0)s$? If yes - in this equation I still have $t,s$ or for example $y,w$: $P: q(y,w)=(-1,2,-3)+(2,1,1)y+(1,2,0)w$?
**(3)**  Assuming all the answers are yes, then I have:$$T(P):  \begin{cases} 2y_{1}+y_{2}+y_{3}=0\\ y_{1}+2y_{2}=0 \end{cases}  \Rightarrow  \begin{cases} y_{1}=-2y_{2} \\ y_{3}=3y_{2} \end{cases}  \Rightarrow T(P)=span\left\{ (-2,1,3)\right\} $$Therefore I have: $$P:-2x_{1}+x_{2}+3x_{3}=b$$ $$b=2+2-9=-5$$ $$P:-2x_{1}+x_{2}+3x_{3}=-5$$
 **(4)**  Assuming (3) is correct, is this method equivalent (3)? 
Let $H=af( p_{0},p_{1},p_{2})$, then: $$T(H)=span(p_{0}p{1},p_{0}p_{2})=span((1,0,1),(0,1,0)) \Rightarrow  \begin{cases} y_{1}+y_{3}=0 \\ y_{2}=0 \end{cases}  \Rightarrow \begin{cases} y_{1}=-y_{3} \\ y_{2}=0 \end{cases}  \Rightarrow  \beta=(-1,0,1)$$Therefore I have: $$P:-x_{1}+x_{3}=c$$ $$c=1-3=-2$$ $$P: -x_{1}+x_{3}=-2$$
I'm asking you to dispel my doubts, I will be grateful for every answer!

Comment: What does $T$ mean? It looks like you found the orthogonal complement in (3).

Comment: @mr_e_man $T(P)$ is tangent space to $P$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In (1), the tangent vectors for $H$ should be the *differences* of points, not the points themselves.

$$H:\quad(1,1,0)+\Big((2,1,1)-(1,1,0)\Big)t+\Big((1,2,0)-(1,1,0)\Big)s$$

(2) is correct; parallel planes have the same tangent vectors. It doesn't matter what you call the variables.